# CSS Background-Image not displaying?

Tags: html, css

I've all of a sudden got a problem trying to display a background-image in CSS.

The image is invisible!

I'm trying to use this background image specifically for a certain location on the page, before scrolling down further to another image or background.

Can anyone shed some light on this situation and possibly provide the correct code/explain why I was wrong?

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Move</h1>
        <p> Form healthy habits to take your fitness to the next level. </p>
        <a href="www.google.co.uk"> Start Now </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="supporting">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
          <h2>Move</h2>
          <p>Become more active by tracking your runs, rides, and walks.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="feature">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, a {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

.container {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Main */
.main {
  background-image: url ("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-QkqvzArFkYs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/qw97foQDUbQ/s900-c-k-no/photo.jpg");
  height: 600px;
}

.main h1 {
  font-size: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.main p {
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Supporting */
.supporting {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 80px;
}

.supporting .col {
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.supporting h1,
.supporting h2 {
  color: #ffa800;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.supporting p {
  color: #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.supporting .btn {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Feature */
.feature {
  height: 600px;
}

.feature h1,
.feature h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:50px 0 0;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  height: 600px;
}

.footer h1,
.footer h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding:50px 0 0;
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}


@media (min-width:600px) {
  .main h1 {
    font-size: 200px;
  }

  .supporting .col {
    width: 30%;
  }

  .supporting h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  .supporting p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .feature h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove space between `url` and `(` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste URL in Browser if u can see it then may be add Id to div and hard code inside div, try to modify image size and style using view element in any one of the popular browsers.

Then create css for id and try it again .. Even I m new to Css but it always works ..

Or replace HTTP instead of HTTP.. if u dont have certificate then may be it will not show up ..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just remove the space in the CSS?

```
background-image: url("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-QkqvzArFkYs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/qw97foQDUbQ/s900-c-k-no/photo.jpg");
```